# How to mask values in complex json structure using dataweave?

Tags: mule-studio, mule-el, dataweave

I want to mask the element in the json. descID element in the below json should be masked. Could you please suggest.

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "statusCode": "19x9s011",
    "statusDescription": "Service: XYZ IOP ; country: india ; Locale:en-US ; SourceId:KOP; ApiUid: 644e1dd7-2a7f-18fb-b8ed-ed78c3f899s2c2b; Description: The NMK profile call was successful.",
    "details": {
        "descID": "11840000000012698",
        "Code": "XX",
        "languageCode": "en",
        "profile": {
            "base": {
                "username": "abc",
                "firstName": "xc",
                "middleName": "test",
                "lastName": "123",
                "shortName": "xc",
                "displayName": "D",
                "suffix": "T",
                "prefix": "E"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I might use something like to mask the data:

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/json
%output application/json


%var keyToEncrypt = ['descID']

%function encrypt(val) "*****"

%function needsEncrypt(key) (sizeOf (keyToEncrypt find key)) > 0


%function maskSensitiveData(value) value mapObject ({
($$) : maskSensitiveData($) when $ is :object otherwise $
} unless needsEncrypt($$ as :string) otherwise {
($$) : encrypt($)
})

---

maskSensitiveData(payload)
```

This is taken verbatim from https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/training-dev/encrypt-specific-xml-tags-with-the-power-of-dataweave/

If you need to remove the field altogether, then I might use something like:

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/json
%output application/json


%var keyToEncrypt = ['descID']

%function encrypt(val) "*****"

%function needsEncrypt(key) (sizeOf (keyToEncrypt find key)) > 0


%function maskSensitiveData(value) value mapObject ({
($$) : maskSensitiveData($) when $ is :object otherwise $
} unless needsEncrypt($$ as :string) otherwise {})

---

maskSensitiveData(payload)
```

Comment: hi chad, thanks for the response. my requirement is in the output descID element it self should not be there. if it is directly at the first level like status code i can do it like paylaod - staus. but if the element to be removed is under the multiple levels, how exactly to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

1.Convert payload to object

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer doc:name="JSON to Object" returnClass="java.util.HashMap"/>
```

2.Overwrite descID in payload

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[payload.details.descID=flowVars.maskedvalue;]]></expression-component>
```

3.Convert back to json

```
<json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
```